# How to format a local time object in Go with correct minutes?

Tags: time, go

Edit: I have updated the question with code that highlights why the alleged duplicate's solution doesn't work for me

I am trying to take UTC (+0000) times and format them into local times (eastern time in my case) without hard coding any timezone offsets (as to avoid implementing dst correction).

I have the following code which demonstrates the problem I am having

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // Here I load the timezone
    timezone, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/New_York")

    // I parse the time
    t, _ := time.Parse("Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 +0000 2006", "Tue Jul 07 10:38:18 +0000 2015")

    // This looks correct, it's still a utc time
    fmt.Println(t)
    // 2015-07-07 10:38:18 +0000 UTC

    // This seems to be fine - -4 hours to convert to est
    t = t.In(timezone)
    fmt.Println(t)
    // 2015-07-07 06:38:18 -0400 EDT

    // This prints 6:07am, completely incorrect as it should be 6:38am
    fmt.Println(t.Format("Monday Jan 2, 3:01pm"))
    // Tuesday Jul 7, 6:07am
}
```

(https://play.golang.org/p/e57slFhWFk)

So to me it seems that it parses and converts timezones fine, but when I output it using format, it gets rid of the minutes and uses 07. It doesn't matter what I set the minutes to, it always comes out as 07.

Comment: Both the answers in the marked duplicate contains your solution (using `Time.In()`).

Comment: The other question was about how to make a new time instead of parse into a timezone which I am trying to do with ParseInLocation

Comment: You are printing the time wihtout the location. You can do 

    `.Println(t.Format("Monday Jan 2, 3:01pm (MST)"))`

to print the time with the Location information. Also t.UTC() works. Your math is reversed. 

    `// This looks correct, 20 - 0400 = 16 = 4pm`


The time should be added to get the UTC time. So UTC time is 12am next day rather than UTC minus 8

[Updated playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/WL9DQtvcBh)

See also the linked answer for `time.In()`

Comment: My math can't be reversed... I used a date returned by twitter at 4pm, and the twitter date said 8pm +0000, then golang converted it to 8pm -0400

Comment: @icza I have updated the question explaining the exact problem I have, including the solution from the "duplicate", which doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Stephen Yes, it is good now. Reopened and answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout (format) strings are incorrect. As noted in the doc of the [time](http://golang.org/pkg/time/) package, the layout string must denote this time:

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
```

When parsing, use the following format string:

```
t, _ := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006", "Tue Jul 07 10:38:18 +0000 2015")
```

And when printing, use this format string:

```
fmt.Println(t.Format("Monday Jan 2, 3:04pm"))
```

This will result in your expected output:

```
Tuesday Jul 7, 6:38am
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0HohAuY239).